# How can I create an additional ExecutionContext that has similar properties to ExecutionContext.global?

Tags: scala

In Scala, as far as I can tell, `ExecutionContext.global` is different from other `ExecutionContext` objects one might typically create using `ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(...)` because it can use `scala.concurrent.blocking` as a signal to spawn additional threads when an initially small thread pool becomes blocked with long-running, possibly io-bound computation. Is there a way to create another such `ExecutionContext`? Looking at the source code, it appears that `ExecutionContext.global` is created in a fairly unique way, through an internal call to `impl.ExecutionContextImpl.fromExecutor(null: Executor)`, which is package-private.

Answer (score 1):

So you can create this pretty easily with this:

```
  scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(null)
```

It will go through the exact same process as `ExecutionContext.global`.

Behind the scenes this is just creating a `ForkJoinPool` with a special `ThreadFactory` for handling `scala.concurrent.blocking` signals. If you want more control you can just create your own `ForkJoinPool` and then provide a `ThreadFactory` doing something similar to what the scala version does([source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/ExecutionContextImpl.scala#L33-L56)) :

```
  class DefaultThreadFactory(daemonic: Boolean) extends ThreadFactory with ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory {
    def wire[T <: Thread](thread: T): T = {
      thread.setDaemon(daemonic)
      thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(uncaughtExceptionHandler)
      thread
    }

    def newThread(runnable: Runnable): Thread = wire(new Thread(runnable))

    def newThread(fjp: ForkJoinPool): ForkJoinWorkerThread = wire(new ForkJoinWorkerThread(fjp) with BlockContext {
      override def blockOn[T](thunk: =>T)(implicit permission: CanAwait): T = {
        var result: T = null.asInstanceOf[T]
        ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(new ForkJoinPool.ManagedBlocker {
          @volatile var isdone = false
          override def block(): Boolean = {
            result = try thunk finally { isdone = true }
            true
          }
          override def isReleasable = isdone
        })
        result
      }
    })
  }
```

Additionally, Akka has an implimentation as well for its [`FJP`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/dispatch/ThreadPoolBuilder.scala#L160-L203).